# Python - How evaluate Internal Rate of Return (IRR) trough interpolation for an array of generic dimension

Tags: python, arrays, finance, computational-finance, irr

Iìm working with Python and I would to define a function which allow to evaluate the internal rate of return (IRR) of a generic investment project trough the interpolation method.
I know there are several module available which allow to evaluate it in a easier way, but I'm interested in evaluate it manually.
In particular, I would to evaluate IRR for a generic array dimension (of cash flows) digited by a generic user, so it could work automatically.

Someone could help me in this task?

Thanks a lot for helps.

Comment: *Someone could help me in this task?* — Sure. [What is your question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: See [ask]. Few are going to write any code for you. Tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and share the results.